# Segfault in Assembly before main

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm writing this assembly code to take input from the command line and print out each factor of that input. Using NASM, I'm compiling with `nasm -f win32 --prefix _ -o lab2.o lab2.s` and `gcc lab2.o -o lab2`. It segfaults and core dumps every time it's run, even if I place a `ret` in the first line of main, and I just can't figure out where it could be encountering a problem. Please help me find what I'm missing.

```
global main
extern printf
extern atoi

section .data
    strFormat db "%d is a factor of %d\n",0

section .bss
    input: resb 64
    cdown: resb 64

section .text
    main:
        mov ebx, [esp+8]        ;ebx now points to the cmd arguments
        mov eax, [ebx+4]        ;eax now points to the correct argument
        push dword eax          ;esp now points to the same argument
        call atoi           ;esp now points an integer
        add esp, 4          ;returns esp after call
        mov dword [input], eax      ;input now points to that integer
        and edx, 0x00           ;edx is now cleared for use in div
        mov ebx, 2          ;ebx now points to 2
        div ebx             ;divides (edx:eax) by arg(ebx), with the remainder in (edx)
        mov [cdown], eax        ;countdown is lowered to this greatest factor
        jmp loop            ;proceeds to the "loop"
        ret

    loop:                   ;divides, checks, and decrements, before looping
        and edx, 0x00           ;clears the register edx for use in div
        mov eax, [input]        ;eax now points to the input integer
        mov ebx, [cdown]        ;ebx now points to the countdown
        div ebx             ;divides input by countdown, with the remainder in edx
        cmp edx, 0          ;if the remainder is zero...
        je fact             ;...jump to factor
        dec dword [cdown]       ;countdown counts down
        cmp dword [cdown], 0        ;if countdown is greater than zero...
        jg loop             ;...jump to the beginning of the loop
        ret

    fact:                   ;prints a factor
        push dword [input]      ;pushes the original integer into the string
        push dword [cdown]      ;pushes the factor into the string
        push strFormat
        call printf         ;prints the string format
        add esp, 12         ;returns esp after call
        jmp loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we run your program as:

```
 lab2.exe 12
```

This is what the stack looks like on Windows at the beggining of your code:

[image]

So, after:

```
mov ebx, [esp+8]
```

We have that `ebx=00000000`

Then `[ebx+4]` send you to an **Acces Violation** when reading `00000004`. Big problem here.

As you can see in the stack image, you can reach the cmd arguments if you do:

```
mov eax, [esp+0Ch]
```

But in windows, you should be using the Win32 API for this:

[GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get pointer to the unparsed cmd line.

[CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parses the cmd line into an array of arguments.

Look at this example: [Getting command line arguments using the Win32 API](http://www.network54.com/Forum/632471/message/1307235592/Getting+command+line+arguments+using+the+Win32+API)

Of course, this may be only the first problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this is, it seems to me to be some Windows-specific error, because I can compile and run this just fine on Linux. (It has other bugs, but it doesn't segfault.)

I can't help you with Windows (since I don't have it) but with that in mind, you may want to focus your debugging efforts on your build environment rather than your own source code.